# Installed Debian. How to connect to WiFi?

Tags: debian, wifi

Please be patient with me. Here's my question.

I don't know how to get WiFi now that i've installed debian. I'm hoping for a simple solution since I don't understand the ins and outs of this operating system.

I'm primarily confused because I don't see any option on the notification bar to choose my wifi. [image]

I've gone through the steps detailed here for gnome but no success. https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

All I'm going to do now is go over each individual comment and see what solution works for me. Please put your input if you have an easier solution.

Comment: What specifically have you tried? What kind of error messages did you get?

Comment: I followed to instructions on here to the T: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

Comment: You most likely require non-free firmware for your wireless adapter. Can you gain a network connection via an ethernet interface? Also what instructions on here do you mean? Please update your post with the specifics of your hardware and any errors you encountered.

Comment: When I run apt-get install network-manager-gnome I still don't get the option to connect to wifi anywhere

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by getting non-free firmware. I have my wifi router next to me. I don't have an extra ether cable now. Also the instructions I'm referring to come directly from this link for the gnome desktop: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

Comment: Let me know what you think please.

Comment: From your link, there are several instructions after `apt-get install network-manager-gnome`. Did you follow them?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't see an option to set up wifi or any new apps.

Comment: Do you have network access? If you are connected to the internet you can update your `sources.list` to be like what is outlined [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList). run `apt-get update` than install your wireless card's firmware. The instructions are listed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi).

Comment: By non-free I mean proprietary or not open source driver. Debian does not configure non-free devices by default like Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Comment: From your link I don't see how to install my wireless card's firmware. The harware I'm using is Broadcom Limited BCM4331 ID 14e4:4331

Comment: @quickquestion, I actually cannot find your specific device. However [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx) is to a related broadcom driver. Install those components using `apt` and follow the steps outlined by user telcoM.

Comment: To be sure, I have to do what's outlined in the link you provided using apt, and what telecoM says?

Comment: @quickquestion, yes you will install the listed drivers using `apt`, so for example `sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3` and then restart the computer for good measure and follow user telcoM's instructions to connect to a wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what the NetworkManager applet should look like in GNOME when there is a usable WiFi adapter present and enabled, and the user has clicked on the applet icon:

[image: NetworkManager applet in GNOME desktop]

Note the signal strength bar-graph at the notification area. If the WiFi adapter is not functional, it should show a disconnected plug-and-socket icon instead.

Many WiFi adapters require firmware to work. The problem with firmware is that it often comes with some restrictions: at minimum, it is closed-source, clearly not compliant with any form of the GPL license. Usually you are forbidden from reverse-engineering it (if your local laws allows the vendor to forbid that). Sometimes the vendor even forbids any re-distribution of the firmware without specific permission, so that Linux distributions must either get a permission to re-distribute the firmware, or only provide a script that will download the firmware from some authorized distributor.

For Debian, the ideal of free and open-source software is very important, and so they split their software repositories into several parts: the **main** part contains only software that satisfies their freeness criteria, and can be used, examined and re-distributed as you see fit. The **non-free** part of the Debian repository includes all the software, documentation and other stuff that comes with some strings attached. For many users, these extra restrictions can be a non-issue.

But for something like a research project that has only a few people working for it and needs to distribute a pre-configured virtual machine image or something like that, it can be very important to know what they can re-distribute worldwide without any restrictions or risk of legal issues.

So, your WiFi adapter most likely requires firmware, and unless you had the foresight to enable the installation of non-free software when installing Debian, you most likely don't have it, and that's why your WiFi connection does not work.

To know which firmware package you'll need, the first step would be to identify your WiFi adapter.

This command should identify most network cards and integrated network interfaces that are not connected by the USB interface:

```
lspci -nn |grep -i network
```

Please edit your question to add the full output of this command: the ID numbers (they will look like XXXX:XXXX) in the output will help in making an exact identification of your WiFi adapter model.

If you know that your WiFi adapter is connected by USB, or the output of the above command does not include anything that looks like a WiFi adapter, then please post also the output of this command:

```
lsusb
```

Again, the ID numbers will be important.

Comment: What do I do now?

Comment: I have the hardware so the first step is finished. The output I got when I ran the command is Broadcom Limited BCM4331 followed by the ID 14e4:4331

Comment: would appreciate your comment on the next step from here @telcoM

Comment: Your WiFi adapter uses a Broadcom chip. According to [this table](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43) it is supported by the b43 driver in standard Debian kernel, but it requires firmware, and Broadcom has not given permission to re-distribute the firmware. Debian has a `firmware-b43-installer` package that can install the firmware automatically for you, but it needs an internet connection to download a Windows driver package from Broadcom and extract the firmware files from it. So if possible, get a wired connection, and run `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: After installing the firmware and rebooting, the WiFi adapter should become usable and you'll no longer need the wired connection.